# php if is bigger than

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I had problem with php I just dont get it,

here is my code

```
$pieces = explode("|", $result);
if (count($pieces) == 3){
    $size = $pieces[2];
    echo "here";
    if($bw>=$pieces[2]){
        $manfi = $bw - $pieces[2];
        echo "<br>$manfi<br>";
        echo $size;
    }
    else{
        echo "is not big!!!";echo $size."aaa". $bw;
   }
```

and here is the out put

> hereis not big!!!183773480 aaa 1000000000000000

i just cant figure it out , how  this number 1000000000000000 is less than 183773480 ?

Comment: Cause 1000000000000000 overflows a normal 32bit size int that PHP uses.

Comment: Are you sure your values are in fact numbers and not strings?

Comment: @j08691 `$pieces = explode("|", $result);` seems like strings for me.

Comment: @j08691 is right, try to cast to int, for example: `(int)$pieces[2];`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - right, which is my point.

Comment: Exactly. `intval` and such works as well.

Comment: Well if `$bw` is a int the problem is the convertion of the `string` `$size` to an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the number `1000000000000000` is of the datatype string. If you then compare it to an integer it will be casted to an integer. Since `1000000000000000` overflows a 32bit integer that PHP uses it will become a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$bw = intval($bw);
$pieces = array_map(intval, explode("|", $result));
if (count($pieces) == 3){
    $size = $pieces[2];
    echo "here";
    if($bw>=$pieces[2]){
        $manfi = $bw - $pieces[2];
        echo "<br>$manfi<br>";
        echo $size;
    }else{
        echo "is not big!!!";echo $size."aaa". $bw;
    }
}
```

I changed $pieces so that it contains an array of integers and I also made sure that $bw contains an integer